# apache hive column comment with CTAS

Tags: apache, types, comments, hive, ddl

Sorry for all the setup.  This is a hive datatype and comment question.

I have a single file in HDFS which combines 4 sets of table data.  Breaking the data out ahead of time is not my preferred option.  The first 4 rows specify the column headers:

*1 col1, col2, col3
*2 cola, colb, colc, cold, col5e
etc....

data rows begin with matching number at position 1 of the header.

1 data, data, data, 
2 data, data, data, data, data, 
etc...

The base hive table is just col0 - col60 for the raw file.  I've tried creating a CTAS table to hold all of the "1" columns and one for the "2" columns where I can specify data type, and comments.  Since the column names vary, I cannot give the columns names on the base table nor can I comment them with column based metadata.

This DDL didn't work but giving an example of what I'm hoping to do.  Any thoughts ?

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
col1 as meaningful_name string comment 'meaningful comment')
as
SELECT col1 
FROM base_hive table
WHERE col1 = 1;

CREATE TABLE foo 
as
SELECT col1 string comment 'meaningful comment'
FROM base_hive table
WHERE col1 = 1;
```

thanks TD

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand much what you are trying to achieve here, but looking at your DDL, I can see some errors. For the correct `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` implementation, pl use the below DDL:

`CREATE TABLE foo (
col1 STRING COMMENT 'meaningful comment')
AS
SELECT col1 AS meaningful_name
FROM base_hive table
WHERE col1 = 1;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that syntax before.  It throws error:
"CREATE TABLE AS SELECT command cannot specify the list of columns for the target table".  I found a way to make it work though.  Just create the table with the column alias and then issue an ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN to add the data type and comment.